# Server NIC vs PC NIC

Tags: network-adapter, hardware-rec

Are there any differences between a Server NIC and a personal computer NIC? Can I use Intel X710 NIC (for instance this model: FH-X710DA4FHBLK) on my PC without problem? Specific motherboard needed? Is there any compromise about throughput or something else when using this kind of NIC on my PC?

Comment: Server Nics are generally more robust and sophisticated, allowing advanced features like Teaming, and will be made to work with media types not commonly associated with client connections. 10GB connections are common in the data center.

Comment: I don't think that nowadays there is a big difference between high-quality server and PC NICs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different cards usually have different features (especially if there are in different price ranges). You should make sure that the card is compatible with your system (driver and the HW-interface connecting it to the mainboard) but other then that you should be good. Be aware that additional features might overwhelm you at first when it comes to trouble shooting, manual tweeking etc.

NOTE: expanding on Frank's comment, you should make sure that that NIC is compatible with your "network media", mainly depending on the type (Ethernet, fibre etc.) and protocol/speed (100MB, 1GB, 10GB, etc.).

Comment: Thanks, Albin. I will buy a server, but now I want to test some features of this NIC. I have an optical switch with 10G ports and I'm able to do some testing. I'm wondering to know whether this card works on both servers and PCs or not. Actually, I faced some OCP NICs on the internet which are different in their interfaces' position to others and that's made me doubt.
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/docs/network-io/ethernet/network-adapters/ethernet-adapter-ocp-nic-3-video.html

Comment: Yeah, form factors are often different, since servers often come for 19'' racks etc. Make sure that you don't only have a compatible interface and driver but that it will physically fit as well.